# Disable postgresql autostart at bootup (mac osx - homebrew)

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have postgres installed in mac osx Lion, which starts the database at boot time. Is there a way to disable the autostart. I prefer to start the postgres process manually.

I used homebrew to install postgres.

```
brew list
ossp-uuid   postgresql
```

Comment: I'm using the [postresapp](http://postgresapp.com) for that kind of task. I know, I'm not really answering your question, but I find the app quite convenient to work with.

Comment: thanks. I may use it aswell, as I just need postgres for testing